# Flutter Unable catch Exception using tryCatch

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch

I can't catch the exception. Has anyone known how to catch it?

This is where is the error is been throwing. I just wrapped it with a try-catch block but it's not helping me, its cant catch it and I don't know what it's a cant catch

This method is coming from my custom BaseDB abstract class and this method is overridden on my custom FirebaseDBService class.

```
  @override
  Stream<Oyuncu> oyuncuStream(String UID) {
    try {
      return usersColRef
          .doc(UID)
          .withConverter<Oyuncu>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Oyuncu.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (Oyuncu model, _) => model.toJson(),
          )
          .snapshots()
          .map((event) {
        // if (event.data() is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        // var jsonDoc = event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        // return Oyuncu.fromJson(jsonDoc);
        if(event.data() is Oyuncu) {
          return event.data() as Oyuncu;
        }else{
          throw Exception('Unable get user from DB');
        }
      });
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print("Test "+e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

My debug console:

```
W/ProviderInstaller(16484): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
E/flutter (16484): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Unable get user from DB
E/flutter (16484): #0      FirestoreDBService.oyuncuStream.<anonymous closure> (package:p763_quiz/data/service/db/firestoreDBService.dart:41:11)
E/flutter (16484): #1      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:213:31)
E/flutter (16484): #2      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (16484): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (16484): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (16484): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (16484): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (16484): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (16484): #8      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (16484): #9      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
E/flutter (16484): #10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (16484): #11     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (16484): #12     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (16484): #13     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (16484): #14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (16484): #15     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (16484): #16     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (16484): #17     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
E/flutter (16484): #18     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (16484): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (16484): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (16484): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (16484): #22     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (16484): #23     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
E/flutter (16484): #24     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
E/flutter (16484): #25     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
E/flutter (16484): #26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
E/flutter (16484): #27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (16484): #28     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter (16484): #29     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter (16484): #30     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
E/flutter (16484): #31     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (16484): #32     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter (16484): #33     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter (16484): #34     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (16484): #35     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (16484): 
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16484): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16484): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/oidim.p763_qui(16484): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

Comment: You are rethrowing the same error caught by the try-catch in your `oyuncuStream` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successfully handled the error with the onError option.

```
  @override
  Stream<Oyuncu> oyuncuStream(String UID) {
      return usersColRef
          .doc(UID)
          .withConverter<Oyuncu>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Oyuncu.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (Oyuncu model, _) => model.toJson(),
          )
          .snapshots()
          .map((event) => event.data() as Oyuncu).handleError((x){
            throw 'There is a problem with your account';
      });

  }
```

I can get it from the caller.

```
  void startListeningOyuncu(String id) {
    oyuncuDBSubs = db.oyuncuStream(id).listen((oyuncu) {
      emit(AuthState.auhtenticated(oyuncu));
    })
      ..onError((x) {
        toastBase.toastService.showToast(text: x.toString());
        add(AuthEvent.logOut());
      });
  }
```

I think we cant use try-catch with the Streams,please inform me if I m wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the keyword 'rethrow'. Because if you add this keyword, you will send the exceptions caught by oyuncuStream to the function where oyuncuStream was called.
--> oyuncuStream should also be wrapped with try-cat where it is called.

Comment: Yes, its another case and i use trycatch where its called.My trycatch should be working but not working cause there is unhandled messeage on console Unhandled Exception: Exception: Unable get user from DB